# Mongodb indexing on N-nested object

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a collection like the following:

```
{
    name: "A",
    age: 50,
    children: [
        {
            name: "B",
            age: 40,
            children: [
                {
                    name: "C",
                    age: 30,
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "D",
    age: 60,
    children: []
}
```

Two different queries I would like to do.

**1) Find anyone meeting specific age. Return the root person and all of its nested children.**

ex)

If we query age = 40, then it will return object A and all of its nested children.

If we query age = 50, then it will return object A and all of its nested children.

For this problem, one solution I was thinking of was creating another field called ageCollection.
It would simply store a list of all the ages inside, and then I can index on this collection. However, I do not want to have to manually maintain this collection as this would be very error prone. Doing it this way means every time a new person is added, I would have to add to the collection and the same goes for deletion. Is there a better way to do this?

**2) Find anyone with the specific name.**

ex)

If we query name = "C", then it will return object C.

If we query name = "A", then it will return object A and all of its nested children.

I'm not too sure how to solve this problem. I suppose I can create a new collection to contain each individual entry; something something like

```
{
    name: "A",
    age: 50,
    children: [
        {
            name: "B",
            age: 40,
            children: [
                {
                    name: "C",
                    age: 30,
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "B",
    age: 40,
    children: [
        {
            name: "C",
            age: 30,
            children: []
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "C",
    age: 30,
    children: []
},
{
    name: "D",
    age: 60,
    children: []
}
```

But again, I do not want to maintain a copy manually, and this approach will contain lots of duplicates.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you flexible enough to change the collection data structure?

Comment: Preferably, I was hoping to keep the current structure and do some type of special indexing, but I couldn't find any way to do it. The amount of data can be huge, and the queries need to be quick.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use projection in your query

Here is the example:

For Query: **Find anyone meeting specific age.**

You can add a field that has a list of all the ages to maintain that list you can use the database trigger

Checkout this documentation on [Trigger](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/)

For Query: **Find anyone with a specific name.**

```
db.collection.find({
  name: "A"
},
{
  children: 0
})
```

Link to Mongo Playground to test the query: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sksr3voSJmM)

**Suggestion:**

It is better to just store the reference rather than store the whole document of the children

Collection can look like this

```
 [
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "age": 50,
    "name": "A",
    children: [
      "B"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "age": 40,
    "name": "B",
    children: [
      "C"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "age": 30,
    "name": "C",
    children: []
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "age": 60,
    "name": "D",
    children: []
  }
]
```

To find the children you can use `$graphLookup` like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$children",
      connectFromField: "children",
      connectToField: "name",
      depthField: "depth",
      as: "children"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "children.children": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Link to Mongo Playground to test the query: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k-JiZgmhCTM)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry if I wasn't clear, but for the "Find anyone meeting specific age", it should also search the children. For example, if I search age=30, it should return C. 

The suggestion for "Find anyone with a specific name" looks promising. I will read up on it some more.

Comment: Okay... do you have any limit on nesting? as MongoDB has https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Nested-Depth-for-BSON-Documents

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! But, the nesting will not be that many.

Comment: Okay... So if you query age=40 you want only B or B with all its children?

Comment: B and all of its children